# MySQL: Problem with a specific reference

Tags: mysql, reference, innodb

I have two tables. On is a table that contains IP Ranges and their respective country attributions (IPGEO table). The other is a table which simply keeps track of the last country the site was accessed from on a per user basis. The idea is that, if the user suddenly accesses the site from another country, I notify the user about this via email.

Now for the actual tables. I have these two:

The IPGeo table that contains the IP ranges

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `politiker_lu`.`IPGeo` (
  `IPFrom` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `IPTo` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `code2` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL ,
  `code3` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL ,
  `Country` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `index1` (`IPFrom` ASC) ,
  INDEX `index2` (`IPTo` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Then, there is the user_geo table that tracks the last country from which the user accessed the site.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `politiker_lu`.`user_geo` (
  `fi_user` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `fi_country` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL ,
  `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fi_user`) ,
  INDEX `fk_user_geo_1` (`fi_user` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_geo_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fi_user` )
    REFERENCES `politiker_lu`.`user` (`id_user` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

These are the tables as they exist. I now want to reference these two tables as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE `politiker_lu`.`user_geo` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_user_geo_IPGeo1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`fi_country` )
  REFERENCES `politiker_lu`.`IPGeo` (`code3` )
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
, ADD INDEX `fk_user_geo_IPGeo1` (`fi_country` ASC) ;
```

That Statement however fails with errno 150. Both tables are utf8, both columns have the same data-type. Am I missing something vital here?

#### Notes

The table `user` exists and has all the references and is actually irrelevant to the problem. I left it so that I didn't need to edit the statement too much.

Comment: You might want to change your IPfrom and IPto ints to being unsigned. There are no "negative" IP addresses. It's possible for the 'to' value to come out lower than the 'from' one if the range crosses the 2^31 critical boundary.

Comment: @Marc B thanks for the tip, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a unique index or a primary key on the IPGeo.code3 column in order to reference it with a foreign key.

You can see the error by running `show engine innodb status\G` and looking under the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section. The error probably looks something like this:

```
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
for correct foreign key definition.
```

Comment: Hmm, have to try that one out. I haven't defined any column as primary key because they aren't really 'defining' the row (good ol' preaching at school by teachers). Probably will use the unique index however in order to be able to add a reference.

Comment: Oh boy, I can practically screw my design regarding IPGeo and begin anew. Trouble is, I got the list based on the IP ranges, not based on the countries and imported them without much change since it had 110k entries. But because a country can operate on different ranges, a country can be listed multiple times in my table. I need to convert that list to work with 2 tables, one with countries, the other with ranges (with reference to the countries). Only then can I apply a primary key... *sigh*

Comment: A foreign key doesn't have to be unique. MySQL just requires that a field used as a foreign key have an index on it - not that the index be a unique/primary one. MySQL will refuse to create the FK if the two fields are not EXACTLY the same (can't link a varchar(3) to a varchar(4), for instance). The 'show innodb status' output will contain the exact reason, in any case.

Comment: @Marc B: As I mentioned, the key column(s) need to be unique in the parent table. As you say, they do not need to be unique in the child table.